# Is it possible to combine two or more Biquads?

Tags: biquad

I've wrote a Equalizer, and now it apply the Biquads in serie (cascade), I was just thinking if i can combine the biquads it will more efficient than applying one-per-one.

Is that possible?

Comment: Also be a bit careful with "more efficient"! If you're doing this in software, many architectures have instructions and register file sizes that make biquads a very effective structure. (If you're doing this in software, you might also want to consider non-recursive structures, as they can be parallelized/SIMD'ed more easily)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible, yes.  But higher-order IIR filters tend to be less stable and more susceptible to various numerical problems (lost precision, underflow, overflow, etc.), compared to a cascade or bank of suitable partitioned biquad filters.